# Any reason why Internet Explorer won't play HTML5 video on some computers?

Tags: internet, internet-explorer, html, javascript, web-development

We've got a client who is saying an HTML5 video won't play on Internet Explorer 11 on their machine. We've tested it and it works just fine on IE9 and above on the computers in our office. So I was wondering if there are any settings within IE which may be causing this?

Comment: Missing H.264 or MPEG-4 codec ?

Comment: I don't think so, here is the url: http://www.coco-north.com - It works fine on all computers within our office so I suspect it's something to do with the client's computer/settings.

Comment: Have the client tried resetting the IE browser settings?  Internet Options -> Advanced -> Reset.

Comment: No, we'll ask them to do that but I tried screwing the settings on purpose to make the video not work but IE continues to play it.

Comment: Could be they are testing on a VM. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25725591/mp4-video-will-not-play-in-internet-explorer-11